# Codeigniter routing is conflicting on pagination and other URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

CodeIgniter routing is conflicting on pagination and another URL. Actually, I am trying to load the following URL on pagination.

> http://127.0.0.1/Mytredin_codesup/snippets

And for my post, I want to load the following URL

> http://127.0.0.1/Mytredin_codesup/snippets/auto-loader-63152391

But only one URL is running at once.

I am using the following routing

```
$route['snippets/(:any)'] = 'snippets/view/$1';
$route['allsnippets/(:num)'] = 'welcome';
$route['snippets/(:num)'] = 'snippets';
```

Comment: Did you try removing third routing and check?

Comment: shows page not found when i use pagination

Comment: actually i wants to use both urls(above mentioned) on the same route...

Comment: do you mean you want both urls to be routed to same function? In other words, view function in snippets controller?

Comment: $route['snippets/(:num)'] = 'snippets'; this will load index function and $route['snippets/(:any)'] = 'snippets/view/$1'; this will load view function of snippets class

Comment: Do you want the page number in your function for third routing?

Comment: yes that is what i want on this route $route['snippets/(:num)'] = 'snippets'; with pagination to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you want the page number in your function for third routing?
>
> yes that is what i want on this route

So, try changing your third routing rule to,

```
$route['snippets/(:num)'] = 'snippets/index/$1';
```

and your function in `snippets` controller

```
function index(page_no){
    //your code here
}
```

Edit:

Keep your routing rules in this order.

```
$route['snippets/(:num)'] = 'snippets/index/$1';
$route['snippets/(:any)'] = 'snippets/view/$1';
$route['allsnippets/(:num)'] = 'welcome';
```

Problem is using `any` before `num` that `any` will accept any character except `/` and will not get to `num` routing. So, changing routing order will work.

Comment: Now $route['snippets/(:any)'] = 'snippets/view/$1'; stop working

Comment: Try changing the order of routes or use regex instead of `any`

Comment: I again stuck!! what should i do now?

Comment: this http://127.0.0.1/Mytredin_codesup/snippets/auto-loader-63152391 is not working now

Comment: Will that URL always contain characters and numbers joined by hyphens?

Comment: awesome!! thanks !! one last question can i achieve URL like this for pagination - 127.0.0.1/Mytredin_codesup/snippets&page=1

Comment: Yes, but it will be redirected to your index function in `snippets` controller and you will have to get `page` using `$this->input->get('page');`